# shift+Enter JavaScript event: is there a bug on Android stock keyboard?

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard-events

I'm trying to troubleshoot why it seems not possible to **detect a shift+Enter** combination from JavaScript in a simple textarea from popular mobile operating systems.

The core problem is: classic web application that assumes Enter to submit, and shift+Enter for newline, that has problems only with Android.

Basically the code was just the following one:

```
<textarea id="my-textarea"></textarea>
```

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById( 'my-textarea' );
myInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

  // if pressing "Enter"
  if( e.keyCode == 13 ) {

    // and if pressing "shift"
    if (e.shiftKey) {

        // just a new line
        // this does not work on Android
    } else {

        // submit
    }
  }
} );
```

As I will show, it seems this works just as expected in any browser *but Android*, that never has `shiftKey` to any truly value.

You can verify on yourself using this nice tool:

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html

### Event table of "shift+Enter" on most devices

If I understand correctly this is the supposed JavaScript event table on most devices:

[image: events table desktop showing that shiftLeft is activated]

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html

The above correct situation was verified in:

- desktop, physical keyboard, Linux, Firefox 111
- desktop, physical keyboard, Linux, Chromium 111
- mobile, Android 11 LineageOS, virtual keyboard "Hackers Keyboard", with stock browser
- mobile, Android 11 LineageOS, virtual keyboard "Hackers Keyboard", with Firefox 110
- *feel free to add other devices but I'm quite sure that this is the very correct behavior*

### Event table of "shift+Enter" on Android stock keyboard: bug?

But, on many Android devices with the default virtual keyboard, the shift+enter seems just undetected from JavaScript:

[image: events table on Android showing that shiftLeft is never activated]

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html

The above problematic situation was reproduced on:

- mobile, Android 11 LineageOS, stock keyboard AOSP, Firefox 110
- mobile, Android 11 LineageOS, stock keyboard AOSP, DuckDuckGo browser
- mobile, Android 11 LineageOS, stock keyboard AOSP, stock browser

Note that, for all of these problematic cases, I used the default keyboard (stock Android AOSP keyboard). So it really seems like a bug that doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript and it doesn't have anything to do with my anyone web development skills.

### How are you pressing shift+Enter on a virtual keyboard?

Note that I think most virtual keyboards support a simple a way to type the shift+Enter combination. Common examples:

- holding down left shift with a finger, and pressing Enter with another finger
- double tap on shift (so that it stays active) then tap on Enter
- dragging from shift, dropping on Enter (this is a valid gesture for example to write an uppercase letter)

> [image: Android default virtual keyboard with left shift highlighted together with the Enter key]
> For example here you see I double-tapped the left shift (that assumes a more-prominent color), then I pressed Enter.

This specific screenshot comes from Android 11 AOSP which is the one that does not send the shift+Enter combination correctly. Even if, as you can see, it seems just like any other keyboard supporting the shift key (just like the iPhone virtual keyboard, for example, that works instead).

### Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key - Mozilla Web Documentation has a very useful page to explain what should happen, and that indicates that what I'm seeing on the Android keyboard does not adhere to the standard
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event - complete documentation to the `keydown` keyboard event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey - description of the specific flag that should reflect the status of the shift key (and that it simply does not seem to work on this version of this Android keyboard)
- https://github.com/valerio-bozzolan/dom-event-viewer/commit/4a48a9a92818ea5bd31260326dbbc54a5c3c3e45 - I've also forked the DOM Event Viewer to test `<textarea>` elements as well as the default `<input type="text" ... />` element and yes, I can reproduce the same results even with that element

### Questions

1. Is there any known workaround that could be suggested to JavaScript programmers in this situation, to identify shift+Enter from Android default keyboard?
2. Is this in your opinion a bug in Android? If yes, is it known any upstream issue in Android AOSP?

Comment: have you tried using physical keyboard tho? not that it helps, just curious

Comment: @asim: nope but this is interesting, I need an USB adapter for my Android to test. When I will try that I will update the question with these notes for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, your JavaScript problem is very probably **not** fixable by JavaScript.

You got yourself into a cosmic trap since this seems and just related to the default keyboard on most Android phones: the Android AOSP keyboard.

Official homepage / Source code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/

### Why this happens

As mentioned by the user @padeso, probably the root cause is that the backend of the Android AOSP keyboard does not support multi-key events even though its frontend makes it look like. You may be interested in following this bug report on the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/276611340

Edited: it seems this issue is now assigned to a person in Google.

Edited: they said they will respond, but there is no answer at the moment (12 May 2023)

### How to verify if your Android is affected

It's very probable that your Android has this keyboard, and so, you are probably affected.

Anyway here is how to check if you have this problematic virtual keyboard:

1. Settings > Apps > See all
2. Look for "Android Keyboard (AOSP)
3. (package name `com.android.inputmethod.latin`)

### Workarounds

There is no JavaScript workaround to detect the shift+Enter combination and there are really no "alternative events" to detect that. The only concrete fix is contacting your Android users to abandon their default AOSP keyboard and install a "normal" one but - obviously - this is not a feasible option for any website.

I mean, can you really expect to ask such variation to visitors of your website? «To visit this website, change keyboard, yours is bugged.» That would really fix, but it's not feasible.

### So? What do you suggest now?

Probably more than a billion Android devices, at the moment, are affected by this problem. This is not something a JavaScript developer should fight. Give up.

My advice is: avoid relying on the distinction of these two cases on mobile. So, avoid stuff like "send with Enter" and "add newline with shift+Enter". On mobile, make sure the Enter key always just adds a newline, and make sure to have a dedicated button to "submit" (not just the Enter key).

Answer (score 0):

1. **Yes**, this is probably a bug.
2. **No**, there is currently no workaround to suggest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).